# Unable to run JAVAC in Windows 7

Tags: java

Probable JAVA Version 7 Update 67 Installation Problem - javac.exe not found

I think that there is no problem in giving contact numbers and this is not a same query as it is on Windows 7.

After installing I tried to check javac.exe in this dir C:\Java\jdk67\bin and it was not present there. Then I searched C:\ and could not find there.

I installed JDK from the site:

https://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

I think that the installer has some problem.

Regards
Rohan Sarker
www.rohansarker.com
+913324288069 / +917278539338

Comment: `javac` is compiler, and it belongs to JDK (Java Development Kit), not JRE (Java Runtime Environment). Try http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html for Java 8, or http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html for Java 7

Comment: what do you have in bin ? what do you have in parent folder? as @Pshemo said you may have installed jre and not jdk,

Answer (score 0):

Rohan, You can download Java for software development or running applications.

For java software development You need to download the Java JDK (which contains the java compiler javac.exe) at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

For Java application execution You need to download the Java JRE (which contains the java interpreter) at: http://java.com/download/index.jsp

Best regards.